# Webpack recompiles CSS but does not update

Tags: javascript, css, webpack

Using webpack 4.1.1 and webpack-dev-server I have the following webpack.dev.js file

```html
const path = require("path");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')


const src = path.resolve(__dirname, "../");
const build = path.resolve(__dirname, "../../build");
const components = path.resolve(__dirname, "../components");
const icons = path.resolve(__dirname, "../static/icons");
const images = path.resolve(__dirname, "../static/images");
const context = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: `${src}/index.js`,
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: build
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      components: components,
      icons: icons,
      images: images
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css",
      path: build
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html'
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          plugins: [
            "transform-react-jsx",
            [
              "react-css-modules",
              {
                context
              }
            ]
          ]
        }
      },

      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader:'css-loader',
            options:{
              modules: true
            }
          }
        ]},
      {
        test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
        use: [
          'file-loader',
          {
            loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
            options: {
              bypassOnDebug: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg/,
        use: {
          loader: 'svg-url-loader',
          options: {}
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  
};
```

My issue is that when I update a CSS file, i watch the terminal, it says it compiles successfully, however I don't see the changes in the browser.  Even when I navigate directly do localhost:8080/main.css, the old CSS file is still shown.  The only way I can get the CSS to successfully recompile is to stop the dev server and start it all over again.

FWIW, here is my startup script:
`$ ./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server  --config ./src/config/webpack.dev.js --content-base build/ --content-base src/static`

Can someone tell me what I'm missing here?

Comment: could you share contents of `webpack.dev.js`?

Comment: @oniondomes the contents of webpack.dev.js are outlined in the post above